# loop pdf from similar datasets

Tags: r, loops, scatter

I have sixty datasets labled dataset1 to dataset 60
All datasets are structured in the same way but have different data.
I want to get a scatterplot of 2 variables from these datasets and exported to 60 different pdf files.
I tried the code below, and I get 60 pdf files, but they are all the same

```
 for (i in 1:60)
 {
 pdf(sprintf("C:/Users/ME/Desktop/WWD/WWD-Excel/Print/myout[%d].pdf", i))
 dataset<-read.csv(sprintf("C:/Users/ME/Desktop/WWD/WWD-Excel/CSV/dataset[%d].csv", i), header = T, sep = ",", na.strings = "NA")
 plot(dataset$hhexppc, dataset$foodshare)
 dev.off()
 }
```

Comment: nothing is obviously wrong.  Do you get any error messages along the way?

Comment: Maybe your data files are all the same. Add a title so you can check. Try title(sprintf("Plot number %d",i)) - not tested, but might work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you read into `dataset`, and you plot `datasetpoor`. Learn to read your work!

Comment: It was an answer because it should have solved the problem... We're none the wiser...

Answer (score 1):

I set up a mini-test directory called `tmpcsv` containg `data1.csv`, `data2.csv`, and `data3.csv`, ran this code ...

```
setwd("~/R/misc")
for (i in 1:3) {
    pdf(sprintf("print/myout%d.pdf",i))
    dataset <- read.csv(sprintf("tmpcsv/data%d.csv",i))
    plot(y~x,data=dataset)
    dev.off()
}
```

... and got three files `print/myout[1-3].pdf` that reflected the data.  So ... I can't reproduce your problem.